Is it possible to connect from Tibco Spotfire to Azure Databricks using Bearer token?
Is it possible to connect from Tibco Spotfire to Azure Databricks using Bearer token? as i dont want to create traditional way of generating PAT token rather i am exploring options to see if we can use Bearer token method.
One of the option i tried authentication method as UserName and Password, however if i use bearer token in Password field it gives below error message.
enter image description here
Also i was checking existing simba driver option to see if we can use oauth 2.0 option.
enter image description here
Any inputs? suggestions?

Have you checked what are the available options for authenticating in tibco spot fire? or o\nly username and password.

Yes i checked there are only 4 options available which includes kerberos, oauth, username and password, and using odbc connection. So i am checking if anyone has achieved connectivity using API or using certificate or bearer token.
